# Manifest error The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android development.
After build I get error in my manifest file: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="smart.tuke.sk.makac" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission
    android:name="smart.tuke.sk.makac.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TrackerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SummaryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I cannot see there any error. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close tag `</manifest>`, since Google Play Services 3.1.59 permission is now completely unnecessary, use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="smart.tuke.sk.makac" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".TrackerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SummaryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Clean and Rebuild!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't formatted code here correctly. I do have </manifest> closing tag at the end.

Comment: Try now @peter21 and clean and rebuild project!

Comment: Finally I found out that problem was not in this file, but in AndroidManifest.xml (debug).  So my problem is now solved. Thanks for your help anyway.